# Why does taiko spin up two chromium instances on test run?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, getgauge

I created a simple test pack with taiko and gauge. On running the test, i noticed that 2 chromium instance were spun up.

I am not sure if this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.
I had copied over a step definition file which also duplicated a beforeSuite step which meant there were two beforeSuite steps that were opening up browsers prior to test run.